# Reading math function issue

Tags: python, math, input, nameerror

Here is my code

```
import math

try:

    valor = float(input("Give a real number "))
    print("Your value given is: ", value)
except ValueError:

    print("You gave a value not interpretable as a real onel!!")
```

And when my input is `sqrt(2)`, I got this error, anyone knows why?

```
%run "c:\users\aar15\appdata\local\temp\tmpvzauzz.py"

Give a real number sqrt(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

c:\users\aar15\appdata\local\temp\tmpvzauzz.py in <module>()

      1 import math
      2 try:
----> 3     valor = float(input("Give a real number "))

      4     print("Your value given is: ", value)
      5 except ValueError:

C:\Users\aar15\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.1.3253.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.pyc in <lambda>(prompt)

C:\Users\aar15\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.1.3253.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.pyc in <module>()

NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

Comment: Perhaps sqrt(2) is interpreted as a string that needs eval() before casting to float? Or you need math.sqrt(2). It might be good to test whether valor=float(sqrt(2))) gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, but you can still make it work:

```
>>> import math
>>> input()
math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> from math import *
>>> input()
sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```